# link to an anchor on another page with a bunch of images before it

Tags: javascript, html

I have a link to a dom element on another page, the problem is that dom element has a lot of images before it, so when navigate to that element, the page fist works as expected but than jump to anywhere before it. I think the issue is it first calculate the right position before images load, but than loaded images makes page longer than before so the target dom element is displayed at wrong place.

Is there any way to avoid this happening?

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: you can assign fixed width/height to images

Answer (score 0):

did you try this?

```
$(function(){
  window.location.href = "#anchor_id";
});
```

this runs after all DOM Elements are loaded ready and scrolls down to that anchor

Comment: I know this should works, but my needs is that I have an article and some comments related to that, comments should to split into many pages when the number of comments is great than a specific number. In that case, I will place a pagination below the page. And each link in pagination would point to comment block on the other page. So your solution seems not perfect to this needs. But still thanks!